# why am I seeing blank white areas on the right side of my div?

Tags: html, css

I have been facing a weird white blank area on the right side of my div, I tried multiple ways but none is working.

[image]

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.login-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-container">

  <h2>Login</h2>

  {% if message %}
  <div>{{ message }}</div>
  {% endif %}

  <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input autofocus class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>

  Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register here.</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: so much easier to diagnose if there was html to right click on and examine in the inspector

Comment: As @strek said, % is relative to parent's size. This means that if you set the div's width to 100% and it still doesn't cover the full width of the page you have probably a limited parent

Comment: ctrl+shift+i  on browser!  You can easily see where is what and in what size.

Answer (score 0):

inpect the code in your browser by pressing ctrl shift i, check the width of your body tag, if you are using any css library like bootstrap check that as well.